# Return XML as well call a JavaScript function using ternary operator in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator

I am using a ternary operator in JSX to generate some components according to some state set by the User's choice. What I want to do is to also call a JavaScript function or some statement along with generating the components.

This is my related code:

```
          {
            this.state.isTextEditor === 'yes'
              ?
            <Row>
              <Col sm={12}>
                <TextEditor placeholder="Job description here"/>
              </Col>
            </Row>
              :
            <FormGroup controlId="companySignupFormJD">
              <Row>
                <Col sm={12}>
                  <SelectFile
                    ref="JD-file"
                    image={false}
                    controlId={'JD-file'}
                    supportedFiles={supportedDocs}
                    btnLabel={'Select File'}
                    helpText={'PDF, DOC DOCX or TXT'}
                    onChange={::this.setJDFile} />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>
          }
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
{
        this.state.isTextEditor === 'yes'
          ?
        <Row>
          <Col sm={12}>
            <TextEditor placeholder="Job description here"/>
          </Col>
        </Row>
          (and someGlobalVariable += 'classActive')
          :
        ...//same code as above
}
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: why not use a `if` statement?

Comment: can't use it with JSX.

Comment: @Arslan you absolutely *can* use whatever JS syntax you like in JSX. I'm not sure why you think that you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to use `if` in JSX, details can be found here
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

here the relevant code from the documentation-page(above):

```js
var loginButton;
if (loggedIn) {
  loginButton = <LogoutButton />;
} else {
  loginButton = <LoginButton />;
}

return (
  <nav>
    <Home />
    {loginButton}
  </nav>
);
```

So in your case it would be

```
        if(this.state.isTextEditor === 'yes'){
          data =  <Row>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <TextEditor placeholder="Job description here"/>
            </Col>
          </Row>;
        } else  {
         data = <Row>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <TextEditor placeholder="Job description here"/>
            </Col>
          </Row>;
        }
```

and later just add `{data}`, where the jsx should be rendered.

Comment: Thank you! Although, the if statement was used outside JSX but your answer helped me achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operators are so called because they handle three things. You can't spin off multiple operations in one ternary statement. They are mostly used to store values or make one function call.

Just use an `if/else` statement. They are generally more lucid anyway.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I wasn't aware about. But you can't use if/else with JSX. There must be some way around.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I am unfamiliar with JSX. I'll change my response to a comment.